# How to optimize an SQLite3 query

Tags: optimization, sqlite

I'm learning SQLite3 by means of a book ("Using SQLite") and the Northwind database. I have written the following code to order the customers by the number of customers in their city, then alphabetically by their name.

```
SELECT ContactName, Phone, City as originalCity 
FROM Customers
ORDER BY (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM Customers 
      WHERE city=originalCity) 
   DESC, ContactName ASC
```

It takes about 50-100ms to run. Is there a standard procedure to follow to optimize this query, or more generally, queries of its type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general (not only SQLite), it's better to do the count for all values (cities) at once, and a join to construct the query:

```sql
SELECT ContactName, Phone, Customers.City as originalCity
FROM Customers
JOIN (SELECT city, count(*) cnt
      FROM Customers
      GROUP BY city) Customers_City_Count
ON Customers.city = Customers_City_Count.city
ORDER BY Customers_City_Count.cnt DESC, ContactName ASC
```

(to prevent, like in your case, the count from being computed many times for the same value (city))

Answer (score 9):

In the most general case, query optimization starts with [reading the query optimizer's execution plan](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html). In SQLite, you just use

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN statement
```

In your case,

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT ContactName, Phone, City as originalCity 
FROM Customers
ORDER BY (
      SELECT count(*) 
      FROM Customers 
      WHERE city=originalCity) 
   DESC, ContactName ASC
```

You might also need to read the output of

```
EXPLAIN statement
```

which goes into [more low-level detail](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html).